# Before adding the product into cart switching between two quotes

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am trying to switch between two quotes before adding product into quote. For this I have Overriding addAction in CartController.

In Action first I am unsetting the quote id if i have any

```
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $quote_id = $session->getQuoteId();

    //unset the current quote id IsActive(0) and save
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quote_id);
    $quote->setIsActive(0);
    $quote->save();

    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setQuoteId(null);
```

I am getting an extra parameter in url

```
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $free_home_trial = 0;
    if(isset($params['freehometrial'])){
        $free_home_trial = (int)$params['freehometrial'];
    }
```

by this I am checking which quote to load.

```
    if($free_home_trial){
        //check freetrial session Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getFreeTrial()
        //if it is not null then load it
        $freetrial = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFreeTrial();

        if(!is_null($freetrial)){
            $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($freetrial);
            $quote->setIsActive(1)->save();
            //$session->setData($quote);
            $session->setQuoteId($freetrial);
        }
     }else{
        //check for normal session
        //if it is not null then load it
        $normalsession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getNormalCart();

        // var_dump($freetrial);die;
        if(!is_null($normalsession)){
            $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($normalsession);
            $quote->setIsActive(1)->save();
            $session->setQuoteId($normalsession);
        }
     }
```

After `$this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);` I am saving these session if session is not present

```
   //Create session free or normal based on the url parameter

        if($free_home_trial){
            if(is_null(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFreeTrial())){
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setFreeTrial(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId());
            }
        }else{
            if(is_null(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getNormalCart())){
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setNormalCart(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId());
            }
        }
```

I don't know why it is using same quote id for both freeTrial and normal, even if I am saving IsActive as 0 on quote and setting quote id as null on session.

Thanks in advance.

**More clarification**

I want to have two cart that's why i want two quotes and switching between them. When customer click 1st Add to cart then product should be added in 1st cart and when customer click 2nd Add to cart then product should be added in 2nd cart. For this only i have overridden the add action of CartController.

Answer (score 0):

you can switch cart using merge function

```
$quoteA = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load('5');
$quoteB = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load('77');

$quoteB->merge($quoteA);

// Also?
$quoteB->collectTotals()->save();

Zend_Debug::dump($quoteB->getAllItems());
```

Comment: thanks, but i guess merge method is used to merge two quotes but i don't want to do it. I have added clarification about my problem.

Comment: I want to create custom rest api's for add products to cart can tell me what is the procedure? actually I am saving products in quote and it reflects at reports in magento admin panel but do not adding to particular user.